# Gnome-Shell panel disappeared - How to get it back?

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I am on Gnome-Shell and using Ubuntu 11.10.

The problem is after a recent update and also after installing a few extensions, when I logged in to Gnome Shell, I can't find the top panel or AWN. Only the wallpaper is showing and then Conky is displaying.

It also seems to me that for some reason the display effects are not working and that is why AWN is not showing.

Need your help to get back the panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar happened to me. I think the issue is that some of the extensions are buggy and crash the shell. I am not certain but I think this might be because they were badly upgraded from gnome shell 3.0 (I'm not much of  an expert as you can probably tell).

Anyway, I fixed problem by logging on in Unity (so I got a fully workable desktop) and then using synaptic to remove packages starting "gnome-shell-extensions-" -

Try removing the alternative menu status one first- that is reported as buggy as far as I can see.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks for your help. Earlier I tried by removing the extensions that I installed last. That is because I thought there might be some buggy one among them. But that didn't worked. I also removed alternative menu status one but that too didn't work. Now I tried by removing all and then it worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can also open the GNOME extensions settings app (try searching "extensions"), and disable all extensions from there. This is what I did, and it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it's a bug with alternate menu, you must define a user avatar (small picture next your name) and all will be fine.